# Changing axis label color in LightningChart JS

Tags: charts, colors, label, axis, lightningchart

The chart appears with dark background, axis numeric labels in grid positions are yellow.

How do I change axis label colors to white?

E.g. in this example https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/#edit/lcjs_example_0001_simpleScatter

I'm trying

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
  .setInterval(0, 92 * dataFrequency)
  .setTickStyle((visibleTicks) => visibleTicks
              .setLabelFillStyle( color: ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255) })
             )
```

But it's giving SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/classes/visibleticks.html#setlabelfillstyle) it expects you to pass FillStyle, not just color. The solution for your case is as follows:

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
  .setInterval(0, 92 * dataFrequency)
  .setTickStyle( (visibleTicks) => visibleTicks
                     .setLabelFillStyle( 
                         new SolidFill( { color: ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255) } )
                     )
               )
```